# Sonata type model - Parent Category

Tags: php, sonata-admin, symfony, query-builder

I'm trying to add categories with a sonata form. My table **category** in my database looks like this:

[image]

The table contains:

- id
- name
- enabled
- parent_category_id

The **parent_category_id can be null**. So I would like to have a select list where you can have the option to choose a parent category. But I'm a bit stuck on how creating this. My entity **Category** looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Category
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="category", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="fk_category_category_idx", columns={"parent_category_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\CategoryRepository")
 */
class Category
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="enabled", type="boolean", nullable=false)
     */
    private $enabled = true;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Category
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Category")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $parentCategory;

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->getName();
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Category
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set enabled
     *
     * @param boolean $enabled
     *
     * @return Category
     */
    public function setEnabled($enabled)
    {
        $this->enabled = $enabled;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get enabled
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getEnabled()
    {
        return $this->enabled;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set parentCategory
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Category $parentCategory
     *
     * @return Category
     */
    public function setParentCategory(\AppBundle\Entity\Category $parentCategory = null)
    {
        $this->parentCategory = $parentCategory;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get parentCategory
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Category
     */
    public function getParentCategory()
    {
        return $this->parentCategory;
    }
}
```

This is what I have so far without the parent category select:

```
<?php

// src/AppBundle/Admin/CategoryAdmin.php
namespace AppBundle\Admin;

use AppBundle\Repository\CategoryRepository;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AbstractAdmin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;

class CategoryAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
            ->add('name', 'text')
            ->add('enabled', 'checkbox');
    }

    protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
    {
        $datagridMapper->add('name');
    }

    protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {
        $listMapper
            ->addIdentifier('name');
    }
}
```

But now I'm stuck with adding the parent category select (which is not required to select).

Comment: First of all, please, specify, WHERE do you want this selection? As a filter in List view? Or in Edit view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
{
    $datagridMapper
        ->add('name')
        ->add('parentCategory')
        ;
}
```

Basically, Sonata will handle types, options etc. for form field itself if your entity is properly configured. So, just adding property "parentCategory" should add filter by parentCategory and create dropdown with all existing Categories.

But, honestly, your question should be minused, as it sounds like you didn't manage to read Sonata Admin documentation: https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/index.html